# http to https redirect fails on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, iis

Just instated https on my website www.jkp-ads.com. 
My site is run on IIS (not sure which version)

Everything works except for one oddity.
If I enter this url in IE 11:

www.jkp-ads.com/reftreeanalyser.asp

IE redirects to:

https://www.jkp-ads.comreftreeanalyser.asp/

(note the slash moving from after .com to the very end of the url)
Obviously this leads to a "Can't reach this page" error.

This is what my web.config currently contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What is going on here and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After some research the problem could be fixed by emptying the cache of Internet Explorer (Temporary files)